# how to remove the data at certain index in redis list

Tags: redis

I just made a redis list, a example is like

redis list

```
["64107a019441e4145877eb0e_1","64107a019441e4145877eb0e_2","64107a019441e4145877eb0e_3","64107a019441e4145877eb0e_4"
"64107a019441e4145877eb0e_5","64107a019441e4145877eb0e_6","64107a019441e4145877eb0e_7"]
```

i need to remove the data at a selected index.

here is the trying, remove the second item in the list.

```
  await redisClient
            .multi()
            .lRem(`queue`,  1, "64107a019441e4145877eb0e_2" )
            .exec();
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

any idea what goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

What Redis client are you using? Looks like Node Redis.

Why are you using `.multi` and `.exec` here? You should be able to just call `.lRem` and be done with it. It's possible this is the source of your problem:

```js
await redisClient.lRem(`queue`,  1, "64107a019441e4145877eb0e_2" )
```

Also, the [LREM](https://redis.io/commands/lrem/) command does not remove data at a selected index. It removes *count* number of items from the list that match the passed value.

The following rules apply to the value of count:

- If count is positive, LREM will remove matching elements from the start of the list moving to the end up to the value of count. So if you pass in 2 it will remove up to 2 matching elements, starting from the front of the list.
- If count is negative, LREM will remove matching elements from the end of the list moving to the front. So if you pass in -2 it will remove up to 2 matching elements, starting from the end of the list.
- If count is 0, LREM will remove all matching elements. Doesn't really matter if it begins from the start of the list of the end in this case.

So, in your example, you could probably just pass in 0 as the count and be done with it.